# How to get a more up-to-date answer to rise to the top?

Tags: discussion, answers

The answers to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13201/is-there-any-way-to-get-latex-in-onenote?answertab=votes#tab-top) about LaTeX support in OneNote have changed a lot since the question was asked, and since the currently accepted answer was chosen (accepted answer was written in 2011, edited [but trivially so] in 2020).

Short of upvoting more up-to-date answers and hoping that the OP comes back to re-assign a checkmark to a more up-to-date answer, is there anything to do so that casual readers won't get the wrong idea from the top-listed answer (which in my case is at the top, and occupies all of the space 'above the fold', whether I have "Active", "Oldest", or "Votes" selected for the answer order) ... ?  Would editing a more up-to-date answer bump it up, and would that be a legitimate activity?

Comment: related experiment on SO: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/411352/outdated-answers-accepted-answer-is-now-unpinned-on-stack-overflow

Comment: You can lobby to get accepted answers unpinned for tex.se : https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369568/unpinning-the-accepted-answer-from-the-top-of-the-list-of-answers

Comment: One easy way to point readers to newer answers is to leave a comment under the accepted answer with a bit of explanation and a link.

Comment: I see a similar issue with [How to include SVG diagrams in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2099/48973). I posted an [up to date answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/523685/48973) some time ago, but as far as I can tell, the vote distance to the older answers just keeps getting larger. I'll try the comment pointing to the new answer, but I'm not particularly hopeful that this will make it much more visible.

Comment: I'm inclined towards a comment on the question (with a link to the better answer with a request for OP to change the accepted answer) and the same on the accepted answer (with a request for the OP to edit their answer to point to the better answer). Then, after a suitable amount of time (say a week), given sufficient karma, editing the accepted answer to contain the updated info if nothing has been changed.

Comment: related tweet: https://twitter.com/Yaakov/status/1437435979455995913